# linux hosting permissions shared server

Tags: linux, permissions, hosting, shared-hosting

What is the *actual* difference between executable and read permissions on a shared linux server, meaning, how exactly does that relate to what a web visitor can do with, for example a php file? Using godaddy shared hosting, for example, under basic permissions, if web user is not readable, but is executable, the same thing happens as when it is readable but not executable - the php file executes. Also, on a shared linux server, what exactly does making a file writable for web user- someone who doesn't have access to server login but visits the page through a browser do?

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is: nothing. Visitors to a website aren't directly accessing any of the files, PHP or otherwise. They send an HTTP request to the server service (wow, that's terrible wording) on the computer (e.g.: Apache), which then loads the page, executes the PHP, etc. So when you're changing permissions, the pertinent permissions to change are what permissions the Apache account (which, depending on the distro, can be either `nobody` or `www-data`) has on those files. As for what the permissions actually do, [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Permissions) describes it quite well.

You can test this yourself if you have a Linux box. Take a directory with files in it and `sudo chmod -R 744` it. Then, try to `ls -l` into it. You'll be able to see file names, but not any other information about the file (including the contents - `nano`ing any file in that directory will result in creating a new file).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that all this relies on what the web server wants to do, since everything has to go through the web server. It's not like reading a file from a disk. So when you request "index.php" or "index.cgi", you are not reading the contents of the file. The web server will see that the file you're requesting is a program, and it will run the program. Instead of outputting the contents of the file, it will output whatever the program outputs. This is simply a setting, and has nothing to do with permissions. Also, you do not have the ability to change this setting if you're using a shared hosting account.

> on a shared linux server, what exactly does making a file writable [...] do?

You can't make a file "writable" with HTTP. Again, this is not like accessing a file system on a local drive. You can make a server-side program that can handle file uploads, but again, this is has nothing to do with permissions.

I hope this is what you meant. Let me know if you meant something else.